# Why does KBOS have such a short runway?

Tags: runways, airport-design

Runway 15L/33R at Boston Logan is only 2500 ft, which is barely long enough for a Cessna, let alone an airliner. I’m wondering if anyone knows why this runway was built or what purpose it serves. I find it a bit odd considering KBOS is certainly not intended for GA use. I don’t think there are any other class B airports in the country with such a short runway.

Comment: "*It's not uncommon to see Dash-8s and Cape Air Cessna 402s landing on this runway. Never seen a take-off though.*" - https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=327293

Answer (score 24):

15L/35R is actually used for GA purposes although most of the time it is just used as a taxiway. KBOS has a GA ramp and FBO just north of the International Terminal (E). It may surprise you that most of the large Class B airports still have GA traffic and the facilities to support them. Also, a fully loaded C172 only needs about 1200 feet of runway for takeoff at 40C/sea level and 650 to land, so 2550 feet is plenty of runway.

Comment: It's not quite GA, but Cape Air operates 208s at Logan (to/from the Vineyard, Nantucket, etc). Possibly they can use this runway (winds permitting) and not take up slots on the bigger runways.

Comment: Yep. There are a few large U.S. airports (e.g. ATL) where GA is, shall we say, discouraged, but there are also plenty where it's completely normal. In the cities that have Class B/C airports where GA is discouraged, there are usually one or more GA reliever airports near the city. In the case of BOS, Logan is the only thing close to the city itself. The GA airports are all out in the suburbs.

Comment: What does ATL do to discourage GA? I've flown in there several times. Fees weren't even that bad. BOS fees though... whoa!

Airports with 5 active runways (like ATL) are actually easier for GA traffic than some busy Class C airports (like MDW) or smaller Class B airports (DAL).

Comment: Besides fees, the biggest thing to discourage low-end GA is the unavailability of 100LL fuel. Looking at you, KLAX...